# promises : firing all chain of functions at once rather than in series

Tags: javascript, jquery

just trying to get to grips with chaining asynchronous functions together as im learning to use Parse.com

I have a function thats like:

```
delete_post(post_id)
.then(function (){
    _this.show_posts(thread_id);
}).then(function (){
    _this.clear_submit_forum();
})
```

and it works ok!  now when i add a preceding function so it looks like :

```
show_confirmation_alert("are you absolutely sure you want to delete the post?")
.then(function(){
    delete_post(post_id);
}).then(function (){
    _this.show_posts(thread_id);
}).then(function (){
    _this.clear_submit_forum();
})
```

my show confirmation function does this sort of thing:

```
     $popup = create_popup(message)

     var def = new $.Deferred();

     $popup.find(".ok").bind("click", function (){
        def.resolve();
     });
     $popup.find(".cancel").bind("click", function(){
        def.reject();
     });
    $popup.popup();
    $popup.popup("open");
    return def.promise();
```

but when i click ok on the popup all the functions start running and therefore its no use. I really want to have a popup that call a chain of functions without adding handler every time it will make my life so much easier. what could possibly cause this. Is there something i'm really missunderstanding about promises? I thought the function in then cannot run until it recieves a resolved promised from the preceding function so why on earth are they not chaining in series? Thanks

Comment: You are forgetting to `return` a new promise form the `then` callback. Should probably be `return _this.show_posts(thread_id);`, etc, assuming `show_posts` returns a promise. See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/): *"[...] they can return another observable object (Deferred, Promise, etc) which will pass its resolved / rejected status and values to the promise's callbacks."* It also has an example on how to chain promises.

Comment: thanks but ive already done that. i've been starring at it for hours. all functions return a promise or the first example wouldn't work. cant figure out why the popup is breaking it. I should add that the subsequent functions return a parse promise object but i have successfully combined them in other functions.

Comment: You haven't done it in the code you posted though... please update your code with what you really have, otherwise, how are we supposed to really help you?